# Django Associate Already Saved File with Model

Tags: django

I am allowing users to upload images with chunks.  What is the appropriate way to reference the file from the database without resaving the file with FileField? I'm saving as follows:

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
with open('some/file/name.txt', 'wb+') as destination:
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write the chunks to a Django File object and save it to a model's FileField.

Then that saved file will live in your `MEDIA_ROOT` directory, and you will be able to do `mymodel.myfile.url` to share that file's public url if needed.

Comment: once I upload the file don't I already have a Django File Object, request.FILES['file']?  do i still need chunks then? thx again

Comment: No you don't. You can read it as .chunks() if you want to. But you can just .read() what's available inside FILES['file'].